# Change the delegate while displaying controller in popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, popover

I have a mapViewController with the UISearchBar and the listViewController with the UISearchBar too.

They are different controllers and presenting in different tabs, but I have a case when I need to present the listViewController in mapViewController in popover when I begin to edit text in UISearchBar.

Now a mapViewController is a delegate of the UISearchBar in mapViewController and listViewController is the delegate of the UISearchBar in listViewController.

So I implemented in mapViewController the delegate method

```
    - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (!self.listView) {
        self.listView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListViewController"];
        self.listView.showInPopover = YES;                  //HIDES THE UISEARCHBAR IN LISTVIEWCONTROLLER
    }
    if (!self.listViewPopover) {
        self.listViewPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.listView];
        self.listViewPopover.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:searchBar];
        self.listViewPopover.delegate = self;
        [self.listViewPopover presentPopoverFromRect:searchBar.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    }
}
```

So now I need to make the listViewController the delegate of the UISearchBar which is on mapViewController. How can I solve this? Is it possible?

I try to add

```
searchBar.delegate = self.listView;
```

in the method above - but there is no effect. Waiting for your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your listView also conform `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol, you can forward your searchBar's delegate message in your mapViewController's implement to your listView like this:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    // mapViewController's normal code
    [self.listview searchBar:searchBar textDidChange:searchText];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the `listViewController` the `delegate` of the `UISearchBar` which is on `mapViewController`:-

Well just simple thing you can do here, since you have two controllers and two `UISearchBar` so just define tag value inside each `searchbar` and check the condition like this below,
Also before implement below `delegate` method just connect `delegate` to `fileowners` to your both `UISearchBar`

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{  

NSInteger tagVal=[searchBar tag];

if (tagVal==0)
{
//impelement mapviecontroller stuff here
}
else if (tagVal==1)
{
//impelement listviewcontroller stuff here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - In MapViewController.h make a property from listViewController

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) ListViewController *listViewController;
```

2 - Implement this delegate in MapViewController.m

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
      [self.listViewController searchBar:searchBar textDidChange:searchText];
 }
```

3- In ListViewController.m implement this delegate

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
}
```